# Windows found a driver for your device but encountered an error will attempting to install it

Tags: windows-8, drivers, phone

I am trying to install a driver for my `SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab 4`, and I need to install the `SAMSUNG Mobile USB Compositite Device`, because my device shows up in `Unspecified`, and I need `Windows` to recognize it. But when I try to install the driver, the following error appears:

> Windows found a driver for your device but encountered an error will attempting to install it. The data is invalid.

Why in the world is this happening? How can I attempt to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Here you go: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/88af2647-a74a-474b-98d5-3e7cb3db2c28/there-must-be-a-real-solution-to-windows-found-driver-software-for-your-device-but-encountered-an?forum=itprovistahardware

Comment: Or this: http://www.technipages.com/windows-store-has-been-corrupted

Comment: @Jatin That link was useless. I couldn't find the samsung drivers in that folder.

Comment: @Henry would the Android default drivers be OK?

Comment: Try to install [Kies3](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/), then reboot.

Comment: Try uninstalling the USB controller, rather than the Samsung device -> reboot -> let Windows reinstall the drivers -> see if your Samsung gets installed correctly.

Comment: have you tried installing Samsung Kies3, that should have the correct drivers for your device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing usb mode: [link description here](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-109198/)

```
Enable Mass Storage
1.  Connect the device to a computer using the supplied USB cable.
2.  From a home screen, swipe the status bar down to reveal Notifications.
3.  From the Notifications section, tap Connected as a Camera.
4.  From CONNECT AS section, tap Media device (MTP) to enable.
  Enabled when a check mark is present.
Disable Mass Storage
1.  Connect the device to a computer using the supplied USB cable.
2.  From a home screen, swipe the status bar down to reveal Notifications.
3.  From the Notifications section, tap Connected as a media device.
4.  From the CONNECT AS section, tap Camera (PTP) to enable.
  Enabled when a check mark is present.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generic Samsung USB drivers?  These have worked for me before on various Samsung devices and should work on your Tab:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956